# ¿Cómo comparo una expresión regular guardada en una variable?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, shell-script

Tengo un array de cadenas donde los elementos tienen distintos colores y quiero filtrar las cadenas que tengan el color cafe.

```
#!/bin/bash
cafeRegex='^\e[0;33m*{*}\e[0m$'
arrayColores=($(echo -e "\e[0;33m3tia01\e[0m \e[0;37mabuela32\e[0m 2Yo3 \e[1;37mabuelo21\e[0m 
\e[0;32m49hijo1\e[0m \e[0;36m8papa\e[0m \e[0;33m33mama11\e[0m"))
echo "El array: ${arrayColores[*]}"
for familiar in ${arrayColores[*]}
do
    if [[ $familiar =~ $cafeRegex ]]; then
        echo "Los familiares cafes son: $familiar"
    fi
done
```

El output que tengo es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me muestra el array con sus colores pero no se ejecuta la sentencia de filtrar el color cafe, sospecho de la expresión regular.

Comment: Para iterar sobre el array deberías hacer `for i in "${variable[@]}"`, no con `[*]`.

Comment: ¿Por que?, ¿cual es la diferencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en la expresión regular que defines: `^\e[0;33m*{*}\e[0m$`. Esto no coincide, en términos de expresión regular, con ninguna de las cadenas que proporcionas.

Entiendo que lo que quieres buscar es algo del tipo:

- `\e[0;33m3tia01\e[0m`
- `\e[0;33m33mama11\e[0m`

Pero fíjate que esto incluye caracteres como "" o "[" que no se pueden poner tal cual, sino que deben escaparse. También, mencionas alguna `*` entiendo que para referirte a cualquier carácter, pero su uso es incorrecto: `*` indica cantidad, mientras que es `.` lo que usamos para que coincida cualquier carácter.

Por ello, la expresión debería ser así:

```
^\\e\[0\;33m.*\\e\[0m$
```

Esto hará que coincidan las cadenas que...

- empiecen por "\e[0;33m"
- seguidas por muchos (o ningún) caracteres
- y terminen por "\e[0m"

Por tanto, tu script completo sería:

```
#!/bin/bash

cafeRegex='^\\e\[0\;33m.*\\e\[0m$'
arrayColores=("\e[0;33m3tia01\e[0m \e[0;37mabuela32\e[0m 2Yo3 \e[1;37mabuelo21\e[0m \e[0;32m49hijo1\e[0m \e[0;36m8papa\e[0m \e[0;33m33mama11\e[0m")

for familiar in ${arrayColores[@]}
do
    if [[ $familiar =~ $cafeRegex ]]; then
        echo "Los familiares cafes son: $familiar"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta amigo, parece que la expresion que me das es correcta pero aun asi el codigo no filtra las cadenas de color cafe, puse la expresion tal cual y probe pero nada, tambien cambie el [*] por el [@] en el for pero dio el mismo resultado, ¿crees que se trate de un error del codigo o hace falta algo en la expresion?

Comment: @AgileSoul actualicé mi respuesta indicando cómo dejé el script entero. Definí el array directamente.

Comment: TIene sentido definir el array directamente, despues de hacer un `echo -e ${arrayColores[*]} se puede observar cada uno de los elementos coloreados aun asi no entendi donde estaba el error, ¿cambiaste la regex?, probe tu codigo y me funciono perfecto solo añadi la opcion -e para ver el output coloreado. Muchas gracias exelente respuesta.

Comment: Ya lo entendi, el error era definir el array coloreando las cadenas directamente, debia definirlo sin colorearlas para que se pudiera filtrar pero... ¿como fue que lo sabias?

Comment: @AgileSoul aaah jaja, me sonó muy raro un `echo` ahí dentro y lo quité de inicio al hacer pruebas en mi máquina, luego se me olvidó comentártelo.